# Can't start sql server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

I want to start the SQL Server Agent (sql server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition), then I did:

1. Open SQL Server configuration manager.
2. SQL Server services.
3. Right click on sql server agent.

but when I right click the start item is disable.

Comment: Is the SQL Server Agent service started?

Comment: I want to start sql server agent

Comment: yes, but under services.msc, is your SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) service disabled?

Comment: check my answer and try

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Go to run type **services.msc**

Right click on the **SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)**

Then check in the properties your startup type might be *disabled* change it to *automatic* or *manual* and try again it will enable the start option

Comment: I check it and set it ti manual , now start button is enable but when i click on it says : sql server agent service started and then stopped. some service stop automatically if they are not in use by another services or programs

Comment: yes your are ri8 check out here to solve your problem http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic186166-146-1.aspx

Comment: sorry i edited my comment follow the link which i have given check out the other services which need to be started

Comment: sorry i couldn't find the answer in follow link which comment?

Comment: This is not working properly.

Comment: This also works on windows 10 with SQL Server 2017 (Which doesn't seem to provide the configuration manager)

Comment: https://nullablereference.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/unable-to-start-sql-server-agent-2017/